# How to handle Registered:"AirSpace::Notification" windows message

Tags: winapi

SO I'm listening to windows messages for drag and drop and I found one I can't find any documentation on:

```
P message:0xC2EB [Registered:"AirSpace::Notification"] wParam:00000000 lParam:00000000
```

Can anyone explain what this is for?

Comment: What software do you have installed? That's a registered window message, a special type of window message with a fixed name that programs can register at will and that exists throughout the entire system. And why are you "listening to windows messages for drag and drop"? What are you really trying to do by doing this? How to do drag-and-drop on Windows is fully documented.

Comment: Registered window messages are private to the apps that use them. They are usually only documented when used for inter-process communications in public APIs. The only reference I can find for the `AirSpace::Notification` message is in a piece of C# source code for a VSTO addin named [ExcelVerticalTab](https://github.com/nk9k/ExcelVerticalTab), in its [`WindowMessageHandler.cs`](https://github.com/nk9k/ExcelVerticalTab/blob/master/ExcelVerticalTab/WindowMessageHandler.cs) source file. The message appears to be used for detecting changes to Excel worksheets for synchronization purposes.

Comment: Thanks Remmy I was hoping it had something to do with detecting changes to Excel worksheets, but could not find anything about it! May I ask what you used to search for this? Did you just search the message in github? I was monitoring with spy++ b\c Excel does not call IDropTarget members for inter process dragging and dropping. I noticed right as I released the left mouse button this AirSpace::Notification message fired. I don't have any VSTO plugins installed yet, but I'm working on writing one.